# Extracting bitmap from a file

Tags: python, heuristics

given a somewhat complex file of unknown specification that among other things contains an uncompressed bitmap file (.BMP), how would you extract it in Python?
Scan for the "BM" tag and see if the following bytes "resemble" a BMP header?

Comment: Why ask a question when you already have the answer?

Comment: Yes, there's another algorithm that magically locates the bitmap embedded inside another file without actually reading the bytes of the other file.  Sadly, it's a proprietary product of a company I can't name.  Just kidding.  What was your question?

Comment: I asked because maybe there was some tool/library that already did that.. Anyway, did somebody downvote my question just because it contains one possible answer? Are we telling people to "just ask it on Stack Overflow" without first looking for solutions on their own, then? :D

Comment: @Joril: your question could be seen as vague.  "how would you extract it?"  There don't seem to be any alternatives to "read the file".  Since you didn't provide many details on the file format, there's not much we can do except speculate idly on what you might want or need or what constraints you face or what alternatives are sensible.

Comment: @S.Lott: I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough in my question, but I really don't know anything about the file format, except that it contains a BMP.. Thanks for your time anyway :)

Comment: @Joril: When you do know something more, then you can ask a more detailed question and perhaps get a more useful answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use the [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) PIL and have it a go at the data. If it can parse it, then it's a valid image. When it throws an exception, then it isn't.

You need to search for the begining of the image; if you're lucky, the image reader will ignore garbage after the image data. When it doesn't, use a binary search to locate the end of the image.

Comment: But what if the file contains other stuff beside the image? Will it be able to extract it ? It would also have to search for it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, about the only thing you can do is search through the file for the 'BM' marker, pull out the following data into a [BITMAPFILEHEADER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183374(VS.85).aspx) and corresponding BITMAPINFO, and see if the values in it look valid (i.e. that the dimensions are sensible, colour depth is reasonable, etc).

Once you have found something that looks reasonable, pull that data out and pass it to the library mentioned in another answer.